# Can 'à' be followed by 'de'? (Paul Valery)

Tags: grammaire

I'm not getting why 'de' follows 'à' in this passage by Valery's La Jeune Parque.  I would think it would be 'des' as in 'some new desires'.

> Me découvre vermeille à de nouveaux désirs,
> Sur le terrible autel de tous mes souvenirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adjectives "des" becomes "de". ([ref. 1](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html), [ref. 2](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html#0481))

*Examples from Kalmbach's grammar*

| des | de |
| --- | --- |
| Il m’a offert des fleurs magnifiques. | Il m’a offert de très belles fleurs. |
| Je vous donne des ex­em­ples différents. | Je vous donne d’au­tres ex­em­ples. |
| L’artiste a dessiné des figures gigantesques dans la neige. | L’artiste a dessiné de gigantesques figures dans la neige. |

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip, didn't see that coming.